# Taking percentile cuts along an axis of ascii data via python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, median, percentile

I want to take not just the median, but different percentile cuts (e.g. 25th, 75th, etc.) of data values (e.g. 2nd column) in bins along an axis (1st column), which is of the following format:

25.4 14.29  15.25  14.58  10.02

34.4 14.34  15.32  14.62  10.03

90.4 14.44  14.82  14.59  8.58

90.6 14.00  14.83  14.60  8.56

54.4 14.00  14.83  14.60  8.56

...

There are thousands of lines like this and they are not evenly distributed in the first column (e.g. if I bin into 0-10, 10-20, etc, there are different numbers of rows in each bin).  I am scratching my head, because I thought I could use numpy.percentile, and read the data into a 2D array arranged into sub-arrays binned according to column one, and use the axis argument to specify taking a percentile cut along the proper axis.  However, numpy.percentile seems to require a rectangular array (i.e. exactly [M,N] values), and is inflexible for this case.

So, I am looking for a way to perform such operations along an axis.  Just to give you an example of how I would take the mean along an axis, here is the usual code I use, relying on numpy.histogram:

```
nval = numpy.histogram(val1,10,range=[0,100])[0]
val2sum= numpy.histogram(val1,10,range=[0,100],weights=val2)[0]
val2mean = val2sum/nval
```

where val1 is column one.  So, my level of python knowledge is rather limiting for doing anything other than a mean, so learning to take percentile cuts and medians along an axis would be very helpful.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should achieve what you're looking for.

```
# First load the data from your file

import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('28674467.txt', delimiter=' ')

x = data[:,0] # Get first column
m = data[:,1] # Get 2nd column

nval, _ = np.histogram(x,10,range=[0,100])

val2sum, _ = np.histogram(x,10,range=[0,100],weights=m)

val2mean = val2sum/nval
```

However, if you run this with your sample data you'll get a `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide` warning due to the zeros in the division. The result in `val2mean` is:

```
[   nan    nan  14.29  14.34    nan  14.      nan    nan    nan  14.22]
```

You can avoid the warning if you filter by zeros:

```
val2mean = val2sum[nval != 0]/nval[nval != 0]
print(val2mean)
```

This will give you the output below:

```
[ 14.29  14.34  14.    14.22]
```

Note: To get the matching edges you need the second parameter from the `np.histogram` function, which you can filter in the same way.

```
val2sum, edges = np.histogram(x,10,range=[0,100],weights=m)

print(edges[nval != 0])
print(val2mean)

[ 20.  30.  50.  90.]    
[ 14.29  14.34  14.    14.22]
```